# concatenating/printing a string literal

Tags: c, string

I'm running into an odd problem with concatenating or printing strings.  I have a char * that can be set to one of a few values of string literal.

```
char *myStrLiteral = NULL;
...
if(blah)
  myStrLiteral = "foo";
else if(blahblah)
  myStrLiteral = "bar";
```

And I have some other strings that I get from library functions or that are concatenations of input - they're either malloc'ed or stack variables.  When I try to print (or concatenate using strcpy() and strcat(), the result is the same), even though I print the string literal last, it prints *over* the initial characters of the entire string I'm constructing or printing.

```
/* otherString1 contains "hello", otherString2 contains "world" */
printf("%s %s %s\n", otherString1, otherString2, myStrLiteral);

/* prints "barlo world" */
```

Am I misunderstanding something about string literals in C?

Comment: sorry, it's actually NULL, i was just being lazy about capitalization - corrected, thanks.

Comment: No, NULL is valid C, but I suspect the poster did not cut and paste so I let it go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that the literals you're receiving contain only the bytes you expect:

```
void PrintBytes(const char *s)
{
    while (*s) {printf("%d ", *s); s++;}
}

PrintBytes(otherString1);
PrintBytes(otherString2);
PrintBytes(myStrLiteral);
```

My suspicion is that one of them contains an embedded control character.

If you don't care about finding out *which* control character is involved, you could simply print the length of each string. If it's longer than it ought to be, there's a control character in there somewhere:

```
printf("%d\n%s\n", strlen(otherString1), otherString1);
```

Comment: Carriage return!  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of is that the otherString2 contains a carriage return, but not a line feed.

to find out

1. You can strlen otherString2 and see if it matches what you see
2. You can look at otherString2 with a debugger and see if 0x0D is before the 0x00 terminating the string.